# Retrieve Telegram Premium Voice-To-Text from API

Tags: telegram

I’m doing kind of research trying to rate Telegram Voice recognition, to do that I need to get text Telegram outputs for certain set of voice messages. I do have Telegram Premium subscription and all I need to do now: somehow automatically (set is rather large) via API (maybe it is possible in Telethon?) make telegram transcribe my audios and in some way get all that recognitions back.
I’ve heard that Telegram uses just Google API, nevertheless point is to get recognitions directly from Telegram. Do you have any ideas of doing that?

TLDR: have set ~1-5k voice recording, want to get back recognitions from Telegram Premium Voice2Text feature

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems, nobody really implemented this into API